# Django + socialauth: login with openid or admin

Tags: django, openid, admin, django-socialauth

i'm trying to implement the [socialauth](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth) module to my django project, but i get a bit confused on its relation toward the admin site.

My problem: the `@login_required` decorator redirects me to the **admin login** page instead of the **accounts/login/** page to log in via openid.

- how do i offer the possibility to the user to log in via admin or openid?

thanks

Comment: it would be a good idea to add an answer to this question with the solution you found and then accept that answer. This will help those who come after you.

Comment: @Manoj: done! thanks i hadn't noticed that it was possible to answer our own questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution:

- in settings.py, change `LOGIN_URL = 'admin'` to `LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'`
- in urls.py add `(r'^accounts/', include('socialauth.urls')),`